# VBNet Textbox AutoComplete

Tags: vb.net, autocomplete, textbox

i was wondering how some programmers made autocomplete functionality such that it also matches character within the string.

Like for example, there are current records in the table of the database and these are:

```
Ants
Apes
Bats
Bees 
Cats
Dogs
Elephants
```

When I start typing letter "E" in the textbox, i want that the autocomplete functionality suggest these records:

```
Apes
Bees
Elephants
```

since all these string contains letter "E"
hope you can help me with this one. thanks :)

Comment: How do you want to show the options? Drop down?

Comment: option is by drop down and should only suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native controls will not work that way (as far I've I can tell); when you use the auto-complete features, it starts populating the list with matching the start of the word.

You'll have to extend the functionality for auto-complete by implementing custom logic to perform substring searches to populate the match list. There is a promising [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694720/combobox-autocomplete-on-substring) on SO for this already.

Comment: That'sa ,long the lines I was thinking, no way I'd have written all that though, well not for free.

Answer (score -1):

insert combobox
insert items into combobox
set dropdownstyle to simple
set autocompletemode to suggestandappend
set autocompletesource to listitems