# Searching letter or word in combo box

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

In my combo box theses following items are there

```
Edward
Isaac Maria
tony Samuel
Vikram Singh
Natasha raghav
krishh
Rahul Krishna
```

When I enter **kr** combo will list all matching words that contains 'kr' in any position i.e., combo will list `vikram, krishh, rahul Krishna` . In combo box Auto Complete Mode is `Suggest` and Auto Complete Source is `Custom Source` but when I  enter **kr** in combo box it only shows the word that starts with **kr**. In combo box 100s of names are there.

Comment: isnt it just a simple foeach loop + .contains() ?

Comment: could this be what you are looking for ?http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/631196/ComboBox-with-Suggest-Ability-based-on-Substring-S

Comment: This might be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694720/combobox-autocomplete-on-substring

Answer (score 1):

In your sql command you have to input code as follows`select custname,dob from Customer where custname like '%kr%';`
**you have to remember that to add "%" in the both side of the Text **what you have want to search**