# How to implement autocomplete combobox that can search substring for my windows form app?

Tags: c#, search, combobox, autocomplete, substring

[image]Here In image as I press i it is showing all books from i. but i want to search 
from sub string like i want all books that contain india anywhere in title

In my program data is fetching from data base.It is already serching from the beginning but now i want to search any substring from it.Code is given below please help me fit it.

```
sRetVal = GlobalFuncs.GetPersonListWithCondition(ref dtPerson, Convert.ToString(cboPersonCategory.SelectedValue));

if (sRetVal == GlobalFuncs.SUCCESS)
{
     var source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
     source.AddRange(dtPerson.AsEnumerable().Select<System.Data.DataRow, String>(x => x.Field<String>("PersonName")).ToArray());

     cboPerson.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source;

     cboPerson.DataSource = dtPerson;
     cboPerson.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
     cboPerson.DisplayMember = "PersonName";
     cboPerson.ValueMember = "PersonID";
}
else
{
     MessageBox.Show(sRetVal);
     return;
}
```

Comment: Is there any error message you are getting? If not, what all you did to acheive the required functionality?

Comment: no there is no error but on requirment i want to make it able to search also substring. Now it searching from the first letter

Comment: If you can give an example of your current functionality and the required functionality, I can really try to help.

Comment: Already asked here, might help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694720/combobox-autocomplete-on-substring?rq=1

Comment: okay i add image of current functionality

Comment: okay I undestand the problem... I will give a try to resolve it.

Comment: Is this the code that is acheiveing the current fucntionality? Could I have some more code and could you please comment, which statement doing what.

Answer (score 0):

```
sRetVal = GlobalFuncs.GetPersonListWithCondition(ref dtPerson, Convert.ToString(cboPersonCategory.SelectedValue));

if (sRetVal == GlobalFuncs.SUCCESS)
{
    var source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    source.AddRange(dtPerson.AsEnumerable().Select<System.Data.DataRow, String>(x => x.Field<String>("PersonName")).ToArray());

    cboPerson.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source;

    cboPerson.DataSource = dtPerson;
    cboPerson.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
    cboPerson.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
    cboPerson.DisplayMember = "PersonName";
    cboPerson.ValueMember = "PersonID";
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show(sRetVal);
    return;
}
```

Keep coding!